# Strange phenomenon going on with a Formula in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

ok, long story short. I have a formula:

```
let x = 2
function formula(x){
   return 1-1/5 * Math.pow(x,2)
}
```

So when i use this formula i get 0.8 as a result but if i use it like this:

```
let x = 2
function formula(x){
   return 4/5 * Math.pow(x,2)
}
```

this returns 4 instead of 0.8.

As 1-1/5 == 4/5 according to this: *can anyone tell me why is this happening*
[image]

Comment: `(1-1/5) * Math.pow(x,2)` and `(4/5) * Math.pow(x,2)`

Comment: If you add parentheses to your first snippet you will see the results match. Like `(1-1/5) * Math.pow(x,2)`.

Comment: [PEMDAS, BODMAS or BEDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: @mplungjan i get 3.2 which is not correct

Comment: Except it is. What is expected result?

Comment: @AneeqAk `4/5 * 2^2 = 0.8 * 4 = 3.2` Seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

[PEMDAS, BODMAS or BEDMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

3.2 is correct - possibly not what you expect, but is correct according to the math you provided

Possibly you get confused that 4*0.8 === 4-0.8

```js
const formula1 = x => 1-1/5 * Math.pow(x,2);   // PEMDAS violation => 1 - (1/(5*4))
const formula2 = x => (1-1/5) * Math.pow(x,2); // PEMDAS 
const formula3 = x => 4/5 * Math.pow(x,2);     // order interchangeable


console.log("2**2 = ",Math.pow(2,2),"\n4/5 = ",4/5,"\n4*0.8 = ",2**2*4/5)
console.log(4 * 0.8)

console.log(formula1(2))
console.log(formula2(2))
console.log(formula3(2))
```